# Wrong blank sides on twosided memoir - discontinuity in odd and even pages

Tags: memoir, double-sided

I'm preparing my thesis using the `memoir` class and the `twoside` option:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,openright]{memoir}
```

I have parts and chapters, and a blank page is always inserted after a new Part page.  However the blank page seems to mess up the continuity between even and odd pages. This means that when I went to print a copy of document the other day some whole parts have the page numbers on the wrong side.

I also have some figures which extend into the margin and if I'd bound what I'd printed these would have been eaten by the binding rather than being on the outside of the page as intended.

An example of what's happening is below:

```
Last page of preamble      - odd page (right of spine), number vii
Part title page            - even page, number 1
Blank page                 - odd page, no number
First page of new chapter  - even page, number 3
Next page of chapter       - odd page, number 4, page number and
                                          header printed on wrong side
```

I have the following in my preamble which might be relevant:

```
\fancyhead{} % clear current definitions
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[LE]{{\scshape \leftmark}}
\fancyhead[RO]{{\itshape \rightmark}}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
```

And this:

```
\begin{document}
\input{./title.tex}
\pagenumbering{roman}\setcounter{page}{1}
\newpage
\begin{abstract}blah\end{abstract}
\newpage
\begin{acknowledgments}blah\end{acknowledgments}
\newpage
\tableofcontent*
\newpage
\listoffigures
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}\setcounter{page}{1}
\include{introduction}
```

Anyone know what's going wrong? As it stands I can't just print and bind, and the issue can't be solved by just adding blank sheets of paper in certain places before binding.

Comment: i can't say for sure that this is what's happening, but often, the problem is in the front matter, with not enough blank pages before the table of contents, so everything after that is off.  a part page should logically be on the right, usually followed by a blank page and then by a chapter, also on the right.  since page numbering restarts with "1" at the beginning of `mainmatter`, everything should alternate properly after that.  just make sure that main page '1' *does* start on a right-hand page.

Comment: `\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}\setcounter{page}{1}` is inherently unsafe as if the current page is odd you will get two odd pages, so when printed all pages will be on the wrong side of a two page spread. `\cleardoublepage` would be safer.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I wondered whether it was up to me to sort out the front matter or whether `memoir` would do it for me.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Indeed `\cleardouble` page fixed the issue for me. I've put it between `\newpage` and `\pagenumbering{arabic}`

Comment: you don't need `\newpage` at all, `\clearpage` will do that.

Comment: How exactly did you make the title page? If that is done inside the `titlingpage` env, then the abstract should automatically go to a right hand page. Also don't pair fancyhdr with memoir, it has a more well integrated header footer system build in.

Comment: Third, please don't post sniplets, makes it a lot harder to test your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}\setcounter{page}{1}
```

is inherently unsafe as if the current page is odd you will get two odd pages, so when printed all pages will be on the wrong side of a two page spread. `\cleardoublepage` would be safer that `\newpage` here.

Comment: Thanks. This fixed the issue. I've removed the last `\newpage` of the frontmatter and replaced it with a `cleardoublepage`.